# How to change VR Tag of Dicom file with ClearCanvas

Tags: c#, dicom, clearcanvas

I am dicomizing digitized ECG data and I want to set the waveform tag's VR value as **OW** but in default clearcanvas set the tag's VR value to **OB**

> The VR value is readonly in clearcanvas library.

Is there anyway to force clearcanvas library set the VR value of Waveform tag (5400,1010) to OW. I think it is a bug in clearcanvas. According to the docs in **Nema**, VR tag should be set to OW to encode the waveform data in words.

Thank you for helps.

Comment: What tag (group,element), you are talking about?

Comment: Waveform data tag for general ecg IOD. If I set bitsallocated tag 16, I should set it as OW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new `DicomTag` with a different VR.

e.g.

```
DicomAttribute aOriginal = new DicomAttributeOB(DicomTags.WaveformData);
DicomTag aBase = aOriginal.Tag;
DicomTag aWaveformDataTag = new DicomTag(DicomTags.WaveformData, aBase.Name, aBase.VariableName, DicomVr.OWvr, aBase.MultiVR, aBase.VMLow, aBase.VMHigh, aBase.Retired);

myDataSet[aWaveformDataTag].Values = myWaveformDataValues;
```